# Need to crop multiple Image and show at the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to upload multiple images like print venue site for showing in the collage were to upload image from different button and then show in different `div`'s on the page after cropping I have already made a function in which first image is shown perfectly where as in the second function in java script it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".previousBoxhide").hide();
    $(".cropBoxhide").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save").click(function() {
    $("#save-hide").hide();
  });
});



$("#close").hide();
$(".previewBtn").click(function(e) {
  $("#close").show();
  $(".preview-image").addClass("previewcss");
  $(".preview-inner").addClass("previewinnercss");
});

$("#close").click(function(e) {
  $(".preview-image").removeClass("previewcss");
  $(".preview-inner").removeClass("previewinnercss");
  $("#close").hide();
});



let result = document.querySelector('.result'),
  img_result = document.querySelector('.img-result'),
  img_w = document.querySelector('.img-w2'),
  img_h = document.querySelector('.img-h2'),
  options = document.querySelector('.options'),
  save = document.querySelector('.save'),
  cropped = document.querySelector('.cropped'),
  dwn = document.querySelector('.download'),
  upload = document.querySelector('#file-input'),
  cropper = '';

// on change show image with crop options
upload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.files.length) {
    // start file reader
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      if (e.target.result) {
        // create new image
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.id = 'image';
        img.src = e.target.result
        // clean result before
        result.innerHTML = '';
        // append new image
        result.appendChild(img);
        // show save btn and options
        save.classList.remove('hide');
        options.classList.remove('hide');
        // init cropper
        cropper = new Cropper(img);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
});

// save on click
save.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get result to data uri
  let imgSrc = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
    width: img_w.value // input value
  }).toDataURL();
  // remove hide class of img
  cropped.classList.remove('hide');
  img_result.classList.remove('hide');
  // show image cropped
  cropped.src = imgSrc;
  dwn.classList.remove('hide');
  dwn.download = 'imagename.png';
  dwn.setAttribute('href', imgSrc);
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box2").click(function() {
    $(".previousBoxhide2").hide();
    $(".cropBoxhide2").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save2").click(function() {
    $("#save-hide2").hide();
  });
});

$("#close2").hide();
$(".previewBtn2").click(function(e) {
  $("#close2").show();
  $(".preview-image2").addClass("previewcss");
  $(".preview-inner2").addClass("previewinnercss");
});

$("#close2").click(function(e) {
  $(".preview-image2").removeClass("previewcss2");
  $(".preview-inner2").removeClass("previewinnercss2");
  $("#close").hide();
});

let result = document.querySelector('.result2'),
  img_result = document.querySelector('.img-result2'),
  img_w = document.querySelector('.img-w22'),
  img_h = document.querySelector('.img-h22'),
  options = document.querySelector('.options2'),
  save = document.querySelector('.save2'),
  cropped = document.querySelector('.cropped2'),
  dwn = document.querySelector('.download2'),
  upload = document.querySelector('#file-input2'),
  cropper = '';

// on change show image with crop options
upload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.files.length) {
    // start file reader
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      if (e.target.result) {
        // create new image
        let img = document.createElement('img2');
        img.id = 'image';
        img.src = e.target.result
        // clean result before
        result.innerHTML = '';
        // append new image
        result.appendChild(img);
        // show save btn and options
        save.classList.remove('hide2');
        options.classList.remove('hide2');
        // init cropper
        cropper = new Cropper(img);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
});

// save on click
save.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get result to data uri
  let imgSrc = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
    width: img_w.value // input value
  }).toDataURL();
  // remove hide class of img
  cropped.classList.remove('hide');
  img_result.classList.remove('hide');
  // show image cropped
  cropped.src = imgSrc;
  dwn.classList.remove('hide');
  dwn.download = 'imagename.png';
  dwn.setAttribute('href', imgSrc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>






<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <section id="outer">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <h6>Customer Care</h6>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <h6><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>001-3001-7676</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h6 class="text-right"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>Sign up & Save more</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <h6>Track Order</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h6>Login</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h6><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>My Cart</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- topbar-->

    <div id="mid-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-10 divCenter">
            <div class="header">

              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <img src="img/website-logo.png" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Search for product, profession, design & more..." />
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default search">Search</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--header-->

            <div id="main-menu">
              <nav class="col-md-12 navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">All<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Business Cards<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Office<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Clothing<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Accessories<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Gifts<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Home & Kitchen<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Greetings<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Brands Store<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                  </ul>

                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- main-menu -->

            <div id="product-section">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <h3>Bistro DuoTone Photo Mug - Orange</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="product">
                      <div class="image">
                        <div class="preview-image"><span id="close">&times;</span></div>
                        <div class="preview-inner">
                          <img src="img/278.png" alt="tshirt" />

                          <div id="coverimg1" class="object" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto1">
                            <img src="img/139.png" alt="cover1" width="100%" height="auto" />
                            <div class="printimgbox1">

                              <div class="box-2 img-result hide">
                                <!-- result of crop -->
                                <img class="cropped" src="" alt="">
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>

                          <div id="coverimg2" class="object" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto2">
                            <img src="img/139.png" alt="cover2" width="100%" height="auto" />
                            <div class="printimgbox2">

                              <div class="box-2 img-result2 hide2">
                                <!-- result of crop -->
                                <img class="cropped" src="" alt="">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div id="coverimg3" class="object"><img src="img/139.png" alt="cover3" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
                          <div id="coverimg4" class="object"><img src="img/139.png" alt="cover4" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
                          <div id="coverimg5" class="object"><img src="img/139.png" alt="cover5" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
                          <div id="coverimg6" class="object"><img src="img/139.png" alt="cover6" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
                          <div id="coverimg7" class="object"><img src="img/139.png" alt="cover7" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
                          <div id="coverimg8" class="object"><img src="img/139.png" alt="cover8" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <small>Note: Embroidery provides best results for LOGO and Text only, so please ensure uploaded photograph includes only logo or text.</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="col-md-12 product-description">
                      <h4>Personalize your design</h4>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span id="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalshirt"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 1</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalshirt2"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 2</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto3"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 3</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto4"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 4</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto5"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 5</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto6"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 6</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto7"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 7</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="designbtn">
                          <span class="shirtModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalphoto8"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload photo 8</span>
                          <span id="deleteinput" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <form>
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                          <label>Quantity</label>
                          <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                          <label>Price<span>Rs. 349</span></label>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default previewBtn">Preview Design</button>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add to Cart</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">
                            <small>I acknowledge that all unedited text will be left blank and any other unedited 
      customization options will be disregarded in the final print. Please preview to confirm.</small>

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Design Name" />
                          <span><a href="#">Save for later</a></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                          <span><a href="#">Next Design <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></span>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--logo-section -->

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- mid-section -->

    <div class="bottombar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <center>Copyright 2018.All Rights Reserved.</center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Modal logo-->
  <div id="myModalshirt" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Logo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-12 previousBoxhide">
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <p>Image Source Option</p>
              <div class="box">
                <span><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload an Image</span>
                <span class="left-input"><input type="file" id="file-input"></span>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">

              <div class="img-uploadbox">
                <div class="imgicon"><img src="img/img-logo.png" alt="imglogo" /></div>
                <div class="uploaddesc">
                  <h4>Click or Drag and Drop image here</h4>
                  <h6>Resolution:300 DPI</h6>
                  <h6>Image Size:344PX By 230PX / 91MM By 61MM</h6>
                  <h6>Image Formats: .png / .jpg / .tiff / .bmp</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- crop modal -->
          <div class="col-md-12 cropBoxshow">
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="boxx">
                <div class="options hide">
                  <label> Width</label>
                  <input type="number" class="img-w" value="300" min="100" max="1200" />
                </div>
                <!-- save btn -->
                <button class="btn save hide" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                <!-- download btn 
  <a href="" class="btn download hide">Download</a>-->
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">

              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="result"></div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- crop modal -->

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal 2 logo-->
  <div id="myModalshirt2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Upload 2 Logo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-12 previousBoxhide">
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <p>Image Source Option</p>
              <div class="box2">
                <span><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload an Image</span>
                <span class="left-input"><input type="file" id="file-input2"></span>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">

              <div class="img-uploadbox2">
                <div class="imgicon"><img src="img/img-logo.png" alt="imglogo" /></div>
                <div class="uploaddesc">
                  <h4>Click or Drag and Drop image here</h4>
                  <h6>Resolution:300 DPI</h6>
                  <h6>Image Size:344PX By 230PX / 91MM By 61MM</h6>
                  <h6>Image Formats: .png / .jpg / .tiff / .bmp</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- crop modal -->
          <div class="col-md-12 cropBoxshow">
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="boxx">
                <div class="options2 hide">
                  <label> Width</label>
                  <input type="number" class="img-w22" value="300" min="100" max="1200" />
                </div>
                <!-- save btn -->
                <button class="btn save2 hide" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                <!-- download btn 
  <a href="" class="btn download hide">Download</a>-->
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">

              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="result2"></div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- crop modal -->

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to edit your question to only show code that is relevant to what you're asking. There seems to be a lot of code here that is unrelated. If you provide a simplified version of your problem it will help you and everyone else to understand it.

Comment: here is the link for the file pls check it would be very helpful

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BDgCtVTRecZBwnyzya0AbKAFSqy-Pn8J

Comment: @AtishayKhare when I run your code, I get an Error right away: `"message": "SyntaxError: redeclaration of let result",  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",  "lineno": 605,  "colno": 4`

Comment: sir please download the full code from the above link